# Duplicate fields in inference the schema when loading XML with Spark

Tags: xml, scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I want to create a schema in this structure:

```
|    |-- Features: struct (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- Feature: array (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

This is my code:

```
StructField( "Features", StructType(
        Array(
          StructField( "Feature", ArrayType(
            StructType(
              Array(
                StructField( "element", StringType, true )
              )
            )
          ) )
        )
      ), true )
```

Result:

```
|    |-- Features: struct (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- Feature: array (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
|    |    |    |    |-- element: string (nullable = true)
```

Any ideia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should omit the innermost `struct`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

val schema = StructType(Seq(StructField("Features", StructType(Seq(
  StructField("Feature", ArrayType(StringType))
)))))

spark.createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext.emptyRDD[Row], schema).printSchema
// root
//  |-- Features: struct (nullable = true)
//  |    |-- Feature: array (nullable = true)
//  |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```